# How does negative look up works in this regex

Tags: python, regex, negative-lookbehind

```
import re

text = """
This is a line.
Short
Long line
<!-- Comment line -->
"""

pattern = r'''(?:^.{1,3}$|^.{4}(?<!<!--))'''

matches = re.findall(pattern, text, flags=re.MULTILINE)

print(matches)
```

OUTPUT with `pattern = r'''(?:^.{1,3}$|^.{4}(?<!<!--))'''` :

```
['This', 'Shor', 'Long']
```

OUTPUT with `pattern = r'''(?:^.{1,3}$|^.{3}(?<!<!--))'''` :

```
['Thi', 'Sho', 'Lon', '<!-']
```

OUTPUT with `pattern = r'''(?:^.{1,3}$|^.{5}(?<!<!--))'''` :

```
['This ', 'Short', 'Long ', '<!-- ']
```

Any number other than 4 in `.{4}(?<!<!--))` causes to display and match <!-- . How?

Comment: `^.{4}` matches 4 characters starting from the beginning while `(?<!<!--)` matches a 0-length character not preceded by `<!--`... which is 4 character long.

Comment: It assures that `^.{4}` did not match `<!--`. Another way to write this is `^(?!<!--).{4}`.

Comment: You have to consider at what position in the string the lookbehind is tested.

Comment: @InSync `^(?!<!--).{4}` is more intuitive to understand `.{4}(?<!<!--))` is not easy to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the regex pattern broken down:

```
(
    ?: # match either
      ^.{1,3}$ # ...a line of 1 to 3 characters, any characters (e.g. "aaa")
      | # ...or
      ^.{4} # ...4 characters of any kind, from the start of a line
        (?<! # # provided those 4 characters are not
            <!-- # these ones
            )  
)
```

Now the basic pattern has been broken down, we can look at the variants:

#### `r'''(?:^.{1,3}$|^.{3}(?<!<!--))'''`

With this one, we can see that the second part of it doesn't work well- it's looking for three characters that don't match a four character string (`"<!--"`, which doesn't make any sense. It's also why `<!-` is part of the output- Python is looking for `<!--`, not `<!-`

#### `r'''(?:^.{1,3}$|^.{5}(?<!<!--))'''`

The same applies for this as for the previous example, except in this case, it's looking for a 5 character string, not a 3 character one. Once again, `<!--`  is found because it is not `<!--`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `?:` in `(?:)` does not mean "*lookbehind for*". Perhaps you meant to say "*match either*"?

Comment: @InSync yes sorry  i did a brainfart